# Initializing a 2d array in one line in Python

Tags: python, list

I am wondering, how i can shorten this:

```
test = [1, 2, 3]
test[0] = [1, 2, 3]
test[1] = [1, 2, 3]
test[2] = [1, 2, 3]
```

I tried something like this:

```
test = [1[1, 2, 3], 2 [1, 2, 3], 3[1, 2, 3]]
#or
test = [1 = [1, 2, 3], 2 = [1, 2, 3], 3 = [1, 2, 3]] #I know this is dumb, but at least I tried...
```

But it's not functioning :|

Is this just me beeing stupid and trying something that can not work, or is there a proper Syntax for this, that I don't know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
test = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

But, if you want to have more number of lists to be created then you might want to go with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like this

```
test = [[1, 2, 3] for i in range(100)]
```

This will create a list of 100 sub lists. The list comprehension is to create a new list and it can be understood like this

```
test = []
for i in range(100):
    test.append([1, 2, 3])
```

**Note:** Instead of doing `test[0] = ...`, you can simply make use of [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) like this

```
test = []
test.append([1, 2, 3])
...
```

---

If you look at the language [definition of list](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays),

```
list_display        ::=  "[" [expression_list | list_comprehension] "]"
```

So, a list can be constructed with list comprehension or expression list. If we see the [expression list](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression_list),

```
expression_list ::=  expression ( "," expression )* [","]
```

It is just a comma separated one or more expressions.

In your case,

```
1[1, 2, 3], 2[1, 2, 3] ...
```

are not valid expressions, since `1[1, 2, 3]` has no meaning in Python. Also,

```
1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

means you are assigning `[1, 2, 3]` to `1`, which is also not a valid expression. That is why your attempts didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code: `test = [1 = [1, 2, 3], 2 = [1, 2, 3], 3 = [1, 2, 3]]` is pretty close. You can use a dictionary to do exactly that:

```
test = {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Now, to call test 1 simply use:

```
test[1]
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a dict comprehension:

```
test = {i: [1, 2, 3] for i in range(3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a list comprehension:

```
test = [[1, 2, 3] for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can do this:

```
test = [[1,2,3]]*3
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

===== Edited ====.
However, Note that all elements refer to the same object

```
# 1. -----------------
# If one element is changed, the others will be changed as well.
test = [[1,2,3]]*3
print(test)
#=>[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
test[0][1] = 4
print(test)
#=>[[1, 4, 3], [1, 4, 3], [1, 4, 3]] # because it refer to same object

# 2. -----------------
# Of course, those elements have the same value.
print("same value") if test[0] == test[1] else print("not same value")
#=> same value

# 3.  -----------------
# Make sure that All refer to the same object
print("refer to the same object") if test[0] is test[1] else print("not refer to the same object")
#=> refer to the same object

# 4.  -----------------
# So, Make sure that All have same id
hex(id(test[0]))
#=>e.g. 0x7f116d337820 
hex(id(test[1]))
#=>e.g. 0x7f116d337820
hex(id(test[2]))
#=>e.g. 0x7f116d337820
```

Comment: don't do this unless you want all rows to be identical